# N(T) and R(T) being subspaces of V and W

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

We've got a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$

Then $N(T)$ is a subspace of $V$
and  $R(T)$ is a subspace of $W$

How can I prove this [theorem]?

+: What is the difference between "Null space" and "Nullity"?

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. The null space of a transformation $T:V\to W$ (which you denote $N(T)$ here) is the subspace of $V$ defined as
$$
\{v\in V:Tv=\mathbf{0}\}.
$$
The word "nullity" refers to the dimension of this subspace.

To prove that $N(T)$ is in fact a subspace of $V$, let $v_1,v_2\in N(T)$. Then $Tv_1=Tv_2=\mathbf{0}$, and you want to prove that $v_1+v_2\in N(T)$ and $cv_1\in N(T)$, where $c\in F$. Do you know how to take it from here?

Comment: I tried proving this theorem just before you posted and ended up with: Let $x \in V$ so we know $T: V \rightarrow W$ so $T(x) \in W$. Therefore by definition of $R(T)$, $R(T(x)) \in W$. Is this proof enough for $R(T)$? I'll look at your NS answer now.

Comment: I'm a little confused, what is $R(T(X))$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know why I wrote that. I was trying to say that $T(x) \in W$ so $R(T)$ by its definition $\{x \in V: T(x)\}$ is a subspace of $W$ but I feel that there's still something missing? And don't worry, I'm always confused :)

Comment: What is $\{x\in V:T(x)\}$? Do you mean $\{T(x):x\in V\}$? And why is this a subspace of $W$?

Comment: That is the definition of $R(T)$.

Comment: @Cayde showing a set is a subset of a vector space is not quite the same thing as showing it is a *subspace*. You have to check two closure rules, and the presence of the $0$-vector.

Comment: Ahh okay. I didn't realize that I guess. Thanks.